# Is there an equivalent of 'this' for generics parameters

Tags: c#, generics

Pseudocode:

```
class A
{
    static A()
    {
        SomeGenericMethod<THISCLASS, U>(); // THISCLASS = A
    }
}

class B
{
    static B()
    {
        SomeGenericMethod<THISCLASS, V>(); // THISCLASS = B
    }
}
```

Is there any language construct (indicated by THISCLASS in the above pseudocode) that statically evaluates to the class a generic is instantiated in?

It might not seem much, but if I have to repeat the generic instantiation above for say 20 classes, having to replace THISCLASS by the respective A each time is an additional source of error.

Comment: No, nothing like that exists.

Comment: I don't think there's a keyword like what you're looking for. You could possibly [use reflection to determine the current class' type at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generics-and-reflection), but that will come with certain performance costs and probably won't be very convenient for return types, etc.

Comment: Consider rewriting this in some way that does not use `static`, then the full power of overload resolution and type inference becomes available. Without that, the best you can probably hope for is a code snippet or T4 template to automate the boilerplate on the syntax level.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve in your generic method? If you are looking for a way to tell from which class a method was called, you might be able to get somewhere with [Caller information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information)

Comment: Too bad. Wasn't sure if only I haven't searched hard enough.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're trying to do something with cross-cutting concerns. Perhaps [Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/use-of-aop-in-cross-cutting-aspect-of-error-handling/) would be useful.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Honestly I thought about T4, but for such a minor thing I would probably end up with something less intelligible than the original. So I am just gonna copy the class name, sh*t happens.

Comment: Depending on what you do with `SomeGenericMethod` and if it's always the same, you might also get away with (ab)using the `class B : MyBase<B>` pattern and make the class itself a type parameter, so you can have (e.g.) `class MyBase<T> { protected readonly static List<T> GenericSomethingSomething = new List<T>(); }`.

Comment: `StackFrame` could be used to compare the type of calling static constructor with the type of first generics parameter, in order to fail early from some `Assert` call. But this is probably overkill. Just be careful..

Answer (score 1):

`Type t = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;` will get you to the current type in a static method/constructor. After that you can get the method info for `SomeGenericMethod` and call [MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2) using that and any other type parameters you need before invoking it.

Comment: Forgot to mention those methods are really slow but if just being used in a static constructor it's probably fine. Also wary of unhandled exceptions in static constructors.